# How to scale down Debian

Tags: linux, debian, opensource-projects

I would like to customize Linux Ubuntu or Debian for my raspberry pi. 
How can I remove packages and Applications from it? And also if possible I would like to know how to change the graphics.

Do i need to download the source code on my workstation and than start developing it or should I do all the necessary changes on a installed Ubuntu?

Once I'm finished,how can I create a installation out of it? Or how can I flash my device with an image?

Comment: I would try the opposite: build a minimalist distro and then grow it as needed. [debootstrap](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap) and [live-build](http://live.debian.net/manual/3.x/html/live-manual/toc.en.html) are probably good places to get started.

Comment: Do U have any tutorials of how to build Minimalist distro? And Another question is should I download the source code first and than modify it. Or should do that directly on the Debian?

Comment: The links in my previous comment are to tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need source code, to install less packages. But if you want something real tiny tiny then you will want to start with a different distro, and add only what you need. Then for that little extra smallness, you would compile from source (optimising for your machine, and size, and disabling features that you do not want), but only when you have selected the software that you need.

For the specific answer to your question `apt-get autoremove <package-name>`. The trick is knowing what to remove. You could start with removing the Windowing System if not needed, it is big (if you choose to do this, then better to start with the server-version).

Comment: So if I dont use the source code, How can I create a complete installation of the change OS? 
As I understand I have to Install Linux on a device and than remove all the Unwanted packages and Application?? And onther question is how can I remove unwanted Applications?

Comment: @arif Because you do not need source code to remove packages. (Or add pre-built ones.)

Comment: Yes but I will need the same configuration to install on many devices. If I make changes on the live-CD. Will be able to get it as installation file to install on other devices.

Comment: @arif Ahhh so you need the tool for making live-CD, not source code.

Comment: Okej, what is the tool that I need to use.

Comment: Short and easy I need to create something to install on devices.

Comment: @Arif that is another question: I don't know the answer, but I have seen it, I know it exists. Now you know the question, you just need to ask some one for the answer.